# A Python "Everything" keyword that always returns True for membership tests

Tags: python

I feel like I want an "Everything" keyword in Python that would have the following properties:

- Any boolean test of the form `x in Everything` would always return True, regardless of x.
- Any attempt to iterate it, such as `for x in Everything` would raise an exception

My motivation is that I would like to have an optional whitelist and test something for membership in it, however I would like the default to simply pass.

So rather than writing:

```
def check_allowed(x, whitelist=None):
    if whitelist is None or x in whitelist:
        print("x is ok")
    else:
        print("x is not ok")
```

I'd like to do:

```
def check_allowed(x, whitelist=Everything):
    if x in whitelist:
        print("x is ok")
    else:
        print("x is not ok")
```

To me, the second version seems simpler and more Pythonic, however I don't know how one would implement such a thing.

Alternatively, I will accept explanations for why the first version is better and this is something I shouldn't desire.

Comment: `[x for x in Everything if x not in x` BOOM! Russell's Paradox

Comment: everything does not support iteration ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
class Everything(object):
    def __contains__(self, other):
        return True

everything = Everything()

print 212134 in everything
print everything in everything
print None in everything
for i in everything:
    print i # TypeError.
```

This class implements the`__contains__` behaviour for the `in` keyword. Thankfully ducktyping allows for us to look like a container and not be iterable.

To read more about `__contains__` click [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)

To be used as such

```
everything_ever = Everything()
def check_allowed(x, whitelist=everything_ever):
    if x in whitelist:
        print("x is ok")
    else:
        print("x is not ok")
```

Comment: I'll note that you can skip the need to define a particular instance of Everything with the everything_ever line, and just allow the function definition to instantiate the class, ie whitelist=Everything().