# Python: String similar to everything

Tags: python-3.x, string-comparison

I need to use string (or int, bool, etc.) which will be same as everything. So this code:

```
user_input = input()
if user_input in *magic_string_same_as_everything*:
    return True
```

should return True everythine, no matter what will user type into console.
Thanks for your help

Edit:
I see, that I've asked verry badly.

I'm trying to get 3 user input in this for cycle:

```
user_input = ["", "", ""] # Name, class, difficulty
    allowed_input = ["", ["mage", "hunter"], ["e", "m", "h"]]
    difficulty = {"e": 1, "m": 2, "h": 3}
    message = ["Please enter your heroic name",
               "Choose character (mage/hunter)",
               "Tell me how difficult your journey should be? (e / m / h)"]

    print("Welcome to Dungeons and Pythons\n" + 31 * "_")

    for i in range(3):
        while True:
            print(message[i], end=": ")
            user_input[i] = input()
            if user_input[i] in allowed_input[i]:
                break
```

Choose of name is without restrictions.

I hope, that now my question makes a sense.

Comment: Why not remove the `if` statement and have only `return True` after getting the input?

Comment: Not sure if I understand it correct, you want to take a user input and return true irrespective of any other condition?

Comment: You could be interested in this: [A Python “Everything” keyword that always returns True for membership tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109479/a-python-everything-keyword-that-always-returns-true-for-membership-tests)

Answer (score 0):

You could just get rid of the if-statement and `return True` without the check or (if you really want to use the if-statement) you type `if(True)` and it will always be true.

Comment: return will only work with functions. If statements don't have anything to return. should use print in this case or assign it to a variable.

Comment: you're right, i thought he actually wanted to return True and has this code in a function

Answer (score 0):

## Initial response

This one liner should work.

**If user inputs anything, it counts as an input & prints '`True`', but if user just hits 'Enter' without typing anything, it returns '`No input`'**

```
print ("True" if input("Type something:") else 'No input')
```

## After your edited question

To achieve what you want, **you can define a function that checks for the user input values & corrects them if incorrect**.

```
import re 
# for user input, a single line of code is sufficient
# Below code takes 3 inputs from user and saves them as a list. Second and third inputs are converted to lowercase to allow case insensitivity
user_input = [str(input("Welcome to Dungeons & Pythons!\n\nPlease enter username: ")), str(input("Choose character (mage/hunter): ").lower()), str(input("Choose difficulty (e/m/h):").lower())]
print (user_input)   # Optional check

def input_check(user_input):
    if user_input[0] != '':
        print ("Your username is: ", user_input[0])
    else:
        user_input[0] = str(input("No username entered, please enter a valid username: "))
    if re.search('mage|hunter', user_input[1]):
        print ("Your character is a : ", user_input[1])
    else:
        user_input[1] = str(input("Incorrect character entered, please enter a valid character (mage/hunter): ").lower())
    if re.search('e|m|h',user_input[2]):
        print ("You have selected difficulty level {}".format('easy' if user_input[2]=='e' else 'medium' if user_input[2]=='m' else 'hard'))
    else:
        user_input[2] = str(input("Incorrect difficulty level selected, please choose from 'e/m/h': "))
    return (user_input)

check = input_check(user_input)
print (check)      #  Optional check
```

In each of the if-else statements, **the function checks each element and if no input/ incorrect input (spelling mistakes, etc.) are found, it asks the user to correct them & finally returns the updated list**.

## Test Output

**With correct entries**
    [Out]: Welcome to Dungeons & Pythons!

```
Please enter username: dfhj4

Choose character (mage/hunter): mage

Choose difficulty (e/m/h):h
['dfhj4', 'mage', 'h']

Your username is:  dfhj4
Your character is a :  mage
You have selected difficulty level hard
['dfhj4', 'mage', 'h']
```

**With incorrect entries**
    [Out]: Welcome to Dungeons & Pythons!

```
Please enter username: 

Choose character (mage/hunter): sniper

Choose difficulty (e/m/h):d
['', 'sniper', 'd']

No username entered, please enter a valid username: fhk3

Incorrect character entered, please enter a valid character (mage/hunter): Hunter

Incorrect difficulty level selected, please choose from 'e/m/h': m
['fhk3', 'hunter', 'm']
```

Answer (score 0):

You want True for non empty string?
Just use user_input as bool.

```
user_input = input()
if user_input:
     return True
```

In your question `Name` is special case, just check it like this and for the rest of input you can use `range(1,3)`.

Alternatively switch to using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
allowed_input = ["\A\S+", "\A(mage|hunter)\Z", "\A[emh]\Z"]    

for i in range(3):
    while True:
        print(message[i], end=": ")
        user_input[i] = input()
        if re.match(allowed_input[i], user_input[i]) :
            break
```